# Add HTTP header to response in java socket server

Tags: java, sockets, http-headers

I'm not sure where or what command to use to add the HTTP header to the response from the server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;

public class Response {

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 9999;
Request request;
BufferedOutputStream output;
//constructor para el output
public Response(BufferedOutputStream output){
    this.output = output;
}
//Set del request
public void setRequest(Request request){
    this.request = request;
}

public void sendResource() throws IOException{

    File file = new File(Java_Server.Web_dir,request.getUri());
    byte [] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    FileInputStream file_out = null;

    if(file.exists())
        file_out = new FileInputStream(file);  
    else{
        String errorMessage = "HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found\r\n" +
      "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
      "Content-Length: 23\r\n" +
      "\r\n" +
      "<h1>File Not Found</h1>";
    output.write(errorMessage.getBytes());
    }

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(file_out);

    try{
        bis.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        output.write(bytearray,0 , bytearray.length);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        return;
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The contents is deliver to the browser but without the HTTP header and if a image is send for example, the browser doesn't show the image, it shows byte for byte.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do is, is to implement a Servlet and run it in a Servlet Container. Then you call the method `setHeader` on the `HttpServletResponse` object:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setHeader("X-Whatever-Header-Name-You-Want", "Value");
    }
}
```